# Exporting a grid view to datatable

Tags: asp.net, winforms, gridview

How can i export a .net `GridView` into a `DataTable`.

I am not setting any data source to the GridView all data are entered by user...

If any body knows please help me..thanks in advance....

Comment: what you mean of "Exporting"? Getting all the Values entered by User in the Grid View in to DataTable?

Comment: @Kalyan: Yes.. to get all values in that grid to a datatable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Following Code will help you in adding the Gridview rows to DataTable

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();    
    for (int j = 0; j < grdList.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        DataRow dr;
        GridViewRow row = grdList.Rows[j];
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```